# Tableau desktop graph not showing but preview is

Tags: graph, desktop, tableau-api

I created a worksheet yesterday. I have not made any changes to the configurations but today my graph is not being displayed.

However, if I hover over the worksheet name it shows me a preview of the graph I have created.

How do I make it show in the main window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what solved the problemm, after speaking to Tableau support:

ODBC drivers (what I was using to connect to my database) are possible to use but not supported by Tableau.
Changing to a Microsoft SQL Server Driver solved the problem. Drivers can be found here:
https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your data is still available.. The Preview is coming from a cache of the workbook..

Comment: It seems the data is still available because I can load the data in the Data Source editor

Answer (score 0):

I have just experienced this behavior.  The problem, in my case, was that I had built a "Set" that required a connection to the Tableau Server, and that connection had not been made when I opened the workbook.

Check to make sure that you are signed in to your Tableau Server from your workbook.

If that is not the problem, check each of your filters.  Remove them and add them back, one by one.  After the problem filter is removed, the worksheet will render normally. Then it is just a matter of fixing the filter.